# Unable to decrement a &BigUint in a loop because a temporary value does not live long enough

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a factorial function but I am getting horrible syntax errors. I have boiled my problem down to a few lines of code. I have tried changing the value assignment to `let value =` but then I just end up with an infinite loop.

```
extern crate num; // 0.2.0

use num::{bigint::BigUint, One};

fn decrease(mut value: &BigUint) {
    while value != &BigUint::one() {
        value = &(value - BigUint::one());
        println!("new value {}", value);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:7:18
  |
7 |         value = &(value - BigUint::one());
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^- temporary value only lives until here
  |                  |
  |                  temporary value does not live long enough
  |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the function body at 5:1...
 --> src/lib.rs:5:1
  |
5 | / fn decrease(mut value: &BigUint) {
6 | |     while value != &BigUint::one() {
7 | |         value = &(value - BigUint::one());
8 | |         println!("new value {}", value);
9 | |     }
10| | }
  | |_^
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime
```

Comment: Those aren't *syntax* errors.

Comment: Where do you believe that the value that you are trying to take a reference to will live between loop iterations?

Comment: I dont know .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the value of `value`... you must take it as `&mut`. Take it as `mut &` don't make a lot of sense. After you could use `-=`.

```
extern crate num; // 0.2.0

use num::{BigUint, One};

fn decrease(value: &mut BigUint) {
    while value != &BigUint::one() {
        *value -= BigUint::one();
        println!("new value {}", value);
    }
}

fn main() {
    decrease(&mut BigUint::new(vec!(42)));
}
```